# ignoring duplicates in Selct data from mysql database

Tags: php, sql

My sql query is

`$data = "SELECT 'rank' FROM 'table' WHERE list='180201'";`

i get the result something like as

*. id---rank---list

1---001---180201

2---001---180201

3---001---180201

4---002---180201

5---002---180201

i want get only 2 result

Comment: You need to understand how to use single quotes.  Also, there is no way that a query that specifies one column can return three.  Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` and `Group BY`

1)

```
   SELECT DISTINCT 'rank ' 
   FROM 'table' 
   WHERE list = '180201';
```

2)

```
   SELECT 'rank' 
   FROM 'table' 
   WHERE list = '180201'
   GROUP BY rank
```

Performance :

A `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` usually generate the same query plan, so performance should be the same across both query constructs. `GROUP BY` should be used to apply aggregate operators to each group. If all you need is to remove duplicates then use `DISTINCT`. If you are using sub-queries execution plan for that query varies so in that case you need to check the execution plan before making a decision of which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'rank' FROM 'table' WHERE list='180201';
```

Comment: Sure, all the best!